# How can I add an admin user in Oracle Unified Directory (OUD) 11g r2?

Tags: oracle, ldap

I'm using OUD 11G R2. I just installed OUD with the default setting and setup an instance.  I tried to add an admin user with the command:

```
./ldapmodify -h localhost -p 1389 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w password --defaultAdd --filename admin.ldif
```

Here is the content of admin.ldif

```
dn: cn=oimuser,cn=Root DNs,cn=config
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
objectClass: ds-cfg-root-dn-user
objectClass: organizationalPerson
userPassword: Oracle123
cn: oimuser
sn: oimuser
ds-cfg-alternate-bind-dn: cn=oimuser
givenName: OIM User
ds-privilege-name: -config-read
ds-privilege-name: -config-write
ds-privilege-name: -backend-backup
ds-privilege-name: -backend-restore
ds-privilege-name: -data-sync
ds-privilege-name: -disconnect-client
ds-privilege-name: -jmx-notify
ds-privilege-name: -jmx-read
ds-privilege-name: -jmx-write
ds-privilege-name: -ldif-export
ds-privilege-name: -ldif-import
ds-privilege-name: -modify-acl
ds-privilege-name: -privilege-change
ds-privilege-name: -proxied-auth
ds-privilege-name: -server-restart
ds-privilege-name: -server-shutdown
ds-privilege-name: -update-schema
ds-privilege-name: -cancel-request
```

I got the error as below:

> The provided entry cn=oimuser,cn=Root DNs,cn=config cannot be added
>   because its suffix is not registered with the network group
>   network-group

Would you please advise how I can fix that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only familiar with OUD 11.1.2.1.0. OUD 11.1.2.1.0 has more than one way to add a root user:

- ldapmodify
  The other way you mentioned works just fine (documentation: [OUD 11.1.2.1.0 Admin Guide, 19.2.1.2 To Create a New Root User](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37116_01/admin.111210/e22648/users_groups.htm#CHDCJEEF)). The problem comes when you try to limit the root user's privileges through the Privilege Subsystem, then you'll have to use the dsconfig tool too.
- Oracle Directory Services Manager GUI
  ODSM is a JavaEE 6 application compressed into an Enterprise ARchive. If you install an Oracle Fusion Middleware 11gR2 stack with Weblogic 10.3.6 as application server, you can create a WLS domain in which you are able to deploy ODSM (eg. on AdminServer). If you are not familiar with FMW I don't suggest this option regarding the huge overhead the configuration & learning needs. Nevertheless, once you configured it properly, the GUI helps a lot! In ODSM, you can find what you need here: Log in -> Configuration -> General Configuration -> Root Users

Hope I helped a little.

PS: I would add to Jacky's answer: You might need to use -X too to trust the admin connector's certificate (if you haven't flagged it trusted by adding it to the JKS truststore).

Answer (score 2):

I got the reason. cn=config is an administrative suffix.

> In general, direct LDAP access to the administrative suffixes (using
>   the ldap* utilities) is discouraged. In most cases, it is preferable
>   to use the dedicated administrative command-line utilities to access
>   these suffixes.
>
> If you must use the ldap* commands to access the administrative
>   suffixes, you must use the administration connector port (with the
>   --useSSL or -Z option).

It works when I use the command:

```
./ldapmodify -h localhost -p 4444 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w Oracle123 --defaultAdd -Z --filename admin.ldif
```

You can verify it by:

```
./ldapsearch -h localhost -p 4444 -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w password --useSSL -b "cn=root DNs,cn=config" "cn=oimuser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change "dn: cn=oimuser,cn=Root DNs,cn=config" to "dn: cn=oimuser,cn=Users,dc=xyz,dc=com"

update **cn=Users,dc=xyz,dc=com** according to your directory structure.